# How to get the reference of new Object in two variables at same time?

Tags: c#

I need to get the reference of new Object in two variables at same time. Somthing like

```
Object o1,o2 = new Object();
```

is this is possible?

Thanks in advance..

Comment: _at same time_ can be very simple or very complicated. Any threading involved?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Try this:

```
Object o1 ,o2;
o1 = o2 = new Object();
```

Comment: Well it depends on what the author means by saying at the same time. If he means "as atomic transaction" your solution will not work.

Comment: @soton I can't think of any scenarios where *at the point of declaration* (so either local variables, or field-initializers) that subtlety would be noticeable / detectable.

Comment: @Marc Gravell Not as posted, but if the two references to this one object were part of the shared mutable state of some class, and the initialization of the references happened during a method call, then one reference could be published as non-null and the other as null.

Comment: @Thomas in that scenario, then `o1 = o2 = ...` doesn't solve it, as the separate `stfld` are only atomic *individually*. If you need to change both at the same time, you'd have to use a `Tuple<object,object>` or similar.

Answer (score 2):

Why not just:

```
object o1 = new object(), o2 = o1;
```

?